# Windsor registration for generic commands/command handlers

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Here's my scenario:

```
public static class DomainCommandProcessor
{
    public static void Dispatch<T>(T command) where T : IDomainCommand
    {
        var serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.Current;

        var handler = serviceLocator.GetInstance<IDomainCommandHandler<T>>();
        if (handler != null)
            handler.Handle(command);
    }
}

public class FakeGenericCommand<T1, T2> : IDomainCommand
{
    public FakeGenericCommand(T1 first, T2 second)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }

    public T1 First { get; private set; }
    public T2 Second { get; private set; }
}

public class FakeGenericCommandHandler<T1, T2> : IDomainCommandHandler<FakeGenericCommand<T1, T2>>
{
    public void Handle(FakeGenericCommand<T1, T2> command)
    {
        // something interesting
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DomainCommandProcessor.Dispatch(new FakeGenericCommand<string, string>("hi", "there"))
```

I can't get the Windsor registration right. The following works great for all of my non-generic commands:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed(namespaceName)
    .BasedOn(typeof(IDomainCommandHandler<>))
    .WithService.AllInterfaces()
    .LifestyleTransient());
```

If I register each possible implementation directly, it works but is obviously sub-optimal:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IDomainCommandHandler<FakeGenericCommand<string, string>>>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(input => new FakeGenericCommandHandler<string, string>())
        .LifestyleTransient());
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Since you are using a DI library, is there any compelling reason for you to resort to Service Location instead of using Dependency Injection? What's the advantage of having this static `DomainCommandProcessor` over an `IDomainCommandProcessor` that you inject into components that need it?

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a textbook-case of needing a [typed factory](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx): I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25502885/3204) a question where I described how to use it

---

This answer is heavily inspired by [this article](http://kozmic.net/2010/03/11/advanced-castle-windsor-ndash-generic-typed-factories-auto-release-and-more/).

Register all your handlers

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
    .BasedOn<IDomainCommandHandler>()
    .WithServiceAllInterfaces());
```

Declare a factory interface that will return the handlers for a command

```
public interface IDomainCommandHandlerFactory
{
    IDomainCommandHandler[] GetHandlersForCommand(IDomainCommand command);
}
```

You need to link your command types to the handlers, which you can do with a custom selector:

```
public class HandlerSelector:ITypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    public TypedFactoryComponent SelectComponent(MethodInfo method, Type type, object[] arguments)
    {
        var message = arguments[0];
        var handlerType = typeof(IDomainCommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(message.GetType());
        return new TypedFactoryComponentCollection(handlerType.MakeArrayType(), new Arguments(arguments));
    }
}
```

Then tell Windsor you want a factory that will return a `IDomainCommandHandler<T>`. Don't code anything for the factory.

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.Register(Component.For<ITypedFactoryComponentSelector>().ImplementedBy<HandlerSelector>());
container.Register(Component.For<IDomainCommandHandlerProvider>().AsFactory());
```

You can now use the factory to retrieve your handlers for a command

```
var provider = container.Resolve<IDomainCommandHandlerFactory>();
var msg = new Type2Message();
var msgHandler = provider.GetHandlersForCommand(msg.MessageType);
```

---

Please note that the handlers in the example are not running against the command itself but have a `Execute` function. If you want to return closed generic objects you need to cast them after resolution since you cannot return different types from one method.

I'd advise you reading the original article since it also contains additional information regarding lifestyle, releasing of components and other interesting points.

---

Here an example of the Selector I use for requests where I specify the request and the response as generic components

```
protected override Type GetComponentType(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
{
    var request = arguments[0].GetType();
    var response = arguments[1] as Type;
    var handlerType = typeof(IHandlerOf<,>).MakeGenericType(request, response);
    return handlerType;
}
```

And here is the result of the call to the factory (T is the request, R the response)

```
var handler = handlerFactory.GetHandler<T>(input, typeof(R));
var requestType = input.GetType();
var responseType = typeof(R);
var handlerType = typeof(IHandlerOf<,>).MakeGenericType(requestType, responseType);
r = (R)handlerType.GetMethod("Handle").Invoke(handler, new object[] { input });
```

Comment: My command handlers are generic and it looks like in your example, they are not. TypedFactoryComponentCollection is also not resolving, are you using the latest Windsor version?

Comment: IDomainCommandHandlerFactory does not deal with generic command handlers

Comment: Indeed, that's what I noted. If you return generic command handlers you need to do some reflection after retrieving your command handler in order to call it as a generic method, since the factory cannot return different closed generic types.

Comment: Edited: this is some code out of context, but this is how I handled the fact that I wanted generic command handlers