# How to get Castle Windsor command/handler based on Message content (not runtime type)

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, command-pattern, typed-factory-facility

I have (non-polymorphic) messages, which I want to handle according to their  MessageType field. It is close to the command-pattern discussed here (and which I have working with tests):

1. [Castle Windsor & Command Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943154/castle-windsor-command-pattern)
2. [Windsor registration for generic commands/command handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998996/windsor-registration-for-generic-commands-command-handlers)
3. http://kozmic.net/2010/03/11/advanced-castle-windsor-ndash-generic-typed-factories-auto-release-and-more/

Execpt, I don't have separate classes or generic types for each `MessageType`. I would prefer not to have to introduce such types (legacy reasons).

Roughly like:

```
public interface IMessage {
   int MessageType { get; }
   IList<byte> Payload { get; }
}
class Message: IMessage {
   // Implementation
}
public interface IHandler {
   void Handle(IMessage message);
}
public abstract class TypedMessageHandler: IHandler {
   public abstract int RequiredMessageType { get; }
   public virtual void Handle(IMessage message) {
     if (message.CommandType != RequiredMessageType)
       throw new ArgumentException(nameof(message)) // More info :)
     InnerHandle(message);
   }
   protected abstact void InnerHandle(IMessage message);
}
class MessageType0Handler: TypedMessageHandler {
   public int RequiredMessageType => 0;
   override void InnerHandle(IMessage message) => // Do stuff;
}
class MessageType1Handler: TypedMessageHandler {
   public int RequiredMessageType => 1;
   override void InnerHandle(IMessage message) => // Do stuff;
}
// Some registration that I can use to dispatch from `msg: IMessage` to 
// `IHandler` with `RequiredMessageType == msg.MessageType`.
```

How can I do this dispatch with Windsor? Preferably with some registrations based on queries on the defined types.

The trick with a TypedFactory from the above articles is not immediately useful.

I've been playing with tagging the handlers with custom attributes, but I can't figure out how to *both*:

1. Get the command argument (IMessage instance), *and*
2. use a custom IHandlerSelector to filter the IHandler implementations based on such an attribute.

Comment: I have a working solution at github.com/slogen/WindsorTests/blob/master/WindsorTests/…, but I don't like it :)

It moves the parameter from the Handle() call to the constructor of the IHandler instance (which is OK for me)

But it requires some "trickery" for registration.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add `RequiredMessageType` to your `IHandler` interface:

```
public interface IHandler
{
    void Handle(IMessage message);
    int RequiredMessageType { get; }
}
```

Than you can create your own Dispatcher:

```
public class Dispatcher
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, IHandler> handlers;

    public Dispatcher(IEnumerable<IHandler> handlers)
    {
        this.handlers = handlers.ToDictionary(h => h.RequiredMessageType, h => h);
    }

    public void Dispatch(IMessage message)
    {
        handlers[message.MessageType].Handle(message);
    }
}
```

And Castle registration would be something like:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));
container.Register(Component.For<Dispatcher>());
container.Register(
Classes.FromThisAssembly()
.BasedOn(typeof(IHandler))
.WithServiceFromInterface(typeof(IHandler)));

//dispatch
var dispatcher = container.Resolve<Dispatcher>();
dispatcher.Dispatch(new Message());
```

Comment: That would require creating instances of (all) IHandler implementations to test whether they can operate on a specific MessageType.

Comment: @HelgeJensen. Yes, because your RequiredMessageType information is on instance of your handler, hence you need them. Castle doesn't know anything about what is inside of your instances, to be able give you concrete one. Castle has only knowledge about types (including their attributes.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to do it would be to register your `handler`s as `named` components following a well-known pattern (perhaps "message-handler-for-N" where N is the `MessageType` and then have a typed factory with a custom [`ITypedFactoryComponentSelector`](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md#custom-itypedfactorycomponentselectors) that given a message picks the name for the handler to resolve.

Comment: I see how that could work. It would require some trickery with the registration to make the naming-process an implicit convention though.I already have a quite nice solution if I can require tricks on registration: https://github.com/slogen/WindsorTests/blob/master/WindsorTests/HandlerDispatching/ByCommandTag/HandlerByCommandTagTests.cs