# Resolve the dependency of Command Handler with castle windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, autofac

I just want to register a generic command handler with castle windsor, this is what I've done in ControllerInstaller:

```
container.Register(
    Classes
        .FromAssemblyContaining<ProductCommand>()
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("CommandHandler"))
        .WithService.AllInterfaces()
        .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

and this is my ProductCommandHandler class:

```
public class ProductCommandHandler :  ICommandHandler<CreateProductCommand>
{
}
```

and also my `ICommandHandle` is this:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    ICommandResult Execute(TCommand command);
}
```

and this is where I get the error:

```
public class DefaultCommandBus : ICommandBus
{
    public ICommandResult Send<TCommand>(TCommand command) 
        where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        var handler = DependencyResolver.Current
            .GetService<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();

        if (!((handler != null) && handler != null))
        {
            throw new CommandHandlerNotFoundException(typeof(TCommand));
        }

        return handler.Execute(command);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate<TCommand>(TCommand command) 
        where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        var handler = DependencyResolver.Current
            .GetService<IValidationHandler<TCommand>>();
        if (!((handler != null) && handler != null))
        {
            throw new ValidationHandlerNotFoundException(typeof(TCommand));
        }

        return handler.Validate(command);
    }
}
```

I solve the issue with autofac this the line below:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)).InstancePerRequest();
```

but I don't know how should I solve it via Castle Windsor, please help me

Comment: I think it is really scary that you have those null checks with exceptions. Instead of doing this, write an integration test that verifies whether every command in the system has a corresponding command handler. This allows you to be notified by your tests instead of at runtime. Much safer.

Comment: btw, what's up with that horrible if check? `(!((handler != null) && handler != null))`. That a reeeaaallly complicated way of doing `if (handler == null)`.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same mechanism as you seem to have in a WCF application where calls are handed to message handlers depending on the message type. The way I use it is the following:

- create a [typed factory](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) for message handlers
- instantiate the command bus (in your case) with an instance of the factory
- for each message let the factory resolve the correct message handler
- call the message handler method

This is heavily based on [this post by Krzysztof Koźmic](http://kozmic.net/2010/03/11/advanced-castle-windsor-ndash-generic-typed-factories-auto-release-and-more/) where he describes pretty much this architecture. You can see [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490329/castle-windsor-a-better-way-to-implement-2-levels-of-nested-factories/25502885#25502885) if you want to see how this is coded