# Castle Windsor & Command Pattern

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am trying to implement a Command, CommandHandler and CommandDispatcher pattern using Castle Windsor without manually asking the container to resolve a CommandHandler based on Command type (which is generally considered an anti-pattern).

I found [this](http://kozmic.net/2010/03/11/advanced-castle-windsor-ndash-generic-typed-factories-auto-release-and-more/) old article, but the implementation of `ITypedFactoryComponentSelector` has changed, so now it returns a Func, instead of `TypedFactoryComponent`.

Anyway, I would really appreciate if someone can shed some light on the "correct" implementation of this pattern.
Current setup (simplified):

```
public interface ICommand {}
    
public class CreateUserCommand:ICommand
{
  public string Name { get;set; }
}

public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand> where TCommand: ICommand
{
    ICommandResult Execute(TCommand command);
}

public class CreateUserCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateUserCommand>
{
    public ICommandResult Execute(CreateUserCommand command)
    {
        // some logic here
        return new CommandResult() {Success = true};
    }
}

public interface ICommandDispatcher
{
    ICommandResult Submit<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand: ICommand;
}

public class CommandDispatcher : ICommandDispatcher
{
    // I DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS:
    IWindsorContainer _container;
    public CommandDispatcher(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public ICommandResult Submit<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : Commands.ICommand
    {
        // I DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS TOO:
        var handler = _container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();
        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Command handler not found for command " + typeof(TCommand).ToString());
        }

        return handler.Execute(command);
    }
}
```

Basically all I want is to configure the container in a way that my WebAPI controller can have a dependency on `ICommandDispatcher` and simply do something like

```
var result = this.commandDispatcher.Submit(new CreateUserCommand("John Smith"));
if (result.Success){
  return Ok();
}
```

Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to find a minimal fully functional solution by combining the Castle Windsor documentation and a few blog posts. I hope my answer will save someone a few hours.

For the base setup and missing code, please refer to my question above (I don't want to duplicate a lot of code).

Firstly we need to create an interface for our factory, but with no actual implementation (this is used by Castle Windsor to create a factory that will provide a particular implementation of your `CommandHandler<T>`:

```
public interface ICommandHandlerFactory
{
    ICommandHandler<TCommand> Resolve<TCommand>() where TCommand : ICommand;
}
```

Then add the following CW Installer code:

```
public class CommandingInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>()
            .Register(
                Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                    .BasedOn(typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
                    .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
                    .LifestyleTransient(),
                Component.For<ICommandHandlerFactory>().AsFactory(),
                Component.For<ICommandDispatcher>().ImplementedBy(typeof (CommandDispatcher)));
    }
}
```

so the *magic* is in this line `Component.For<ICommandHandlerFactory>().AsFactory()` as it tells CW to use your interface to create a factory that you will use in your `CommandDispatcher`:

```
public class CommandDispatcher : ICommandDispatcher
{
    ICommandHandlerFactory _commandHandlerFactory;
    public CommandDispatcher(ICommandHandlerFactory commandHandlerFactory)
    {
        _commandHandlerFactory = commandHandlerFactory;
    }

    public ICommandResult Submit<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : Commands.ICommand
    {
        try
        {
            var handler = _commandHandlerFactory.Resolve<TCommand>();
            return handler.Execute(command);
        }
        catch (ComponentNotFoundException cnfex)
        {
            // log here
            throw cnfex;
        }

    }
}
```

*HUGE GOTCHA*

If you name your factory method something like `GetCommandHandler`, CW will try to resolve a type literally called `CommandHandler` and it will fail as you don't have such type. According to docs [HERE](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md#get-methods-lookup-components-by-name) CW should fall back to non-Get, type-based lookup, but it does not seem to do that and simply spits back a `ComponentNotFoundException`. So name your factory method ANYTHING but Get*

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is an interface-based typed factory, ie a factory that resolves components based on the parameters you are passing it without any implementation and without you needing to resolve the components manually. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490329/castle-windsor-a-better-way-to-implement-2-levels-of-nested-factories/25502885#25502885) is an answer that details how to use the typed factory mechanism, and [here](http://kozmic.net/2010/03/11/advanced-castle-windsor-ndash-generic-typed-factories-auto-release-and-more/) is an article from kozmic.net that details it a bit more.

Comment: Thanks samy, I already found those articles, but unfortunately it still was not working. After a few hours of fighting with this, I finally managed to make it work, I will post a full answer below.
Thanks for your help anyway!